# How did Lex Luthor know what Barry Allen and others called themselves in DCEU?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, lex-luthor

It is mostly common knowledge that Barry Allen has never been called by `The Flash' in BvS. However, when Bruce Wayne explores the META_HUMAN files of Lex Luthor, he comes across videos of these four superheroes. And everyone has been given some kind of name as well as logo. The logos can be understood because, well, that's what they wear on their costumes. But their names are written on the files,

- Wonder Woman has Subject 1920/213_meta_human_alpha_WW
- Cyborg has Subject 1920/213_meta_human_alpha_CY
- Flash has Subject 1920/213_meta_human_alpha_FL,
  and
- Aquaman has Subject 1920/213_meta_human_alpha_AQ.

How does one explain this? Moreover, the Crisis on Infinite Earths from the Arrowverse made the Ezra Miller cameo on the premise that Miller's Flash has never thought of a name in the Snyderverse/DCEU. This is all contradicting. Maybe some kind of explanation can be found here?

I suppose the superheroes already have had their names established before, which Lex Luthor had known from his detective work. But this small point was missed by Arrowverse-Crisis? I am not sure how an explanation can be brought about here.

Comment: Same way how Wonder Woman's file is titled Wonder woman, Cyborg's file is titled Cyborg and Aquaman's file is titled Aquaman. None of them had these names; Lex just gave them fancy ones.

Comment: Okay, so it's just a coincidence that Lex's fancy names for the heroes are shorthand for their actual names?

Comment: Are any of them referred to by their traditional superhero names in the DCEU? I remember a lot of "Diana", not a lot of "She's some kind of Wonder Woman!"

Comment: It's just that the initials that Lex gave are shorthand for their superhero names. How can that be explained?

Comment: Lex Luthor reads comic books?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite  Arthur Curry calls himself "Aquaman" at the end of the eponymous movie. Unless Lex Luthor misspelled his last name (Arthur Qurry?)  "AQ" seems remarkably prescient.

Comment: @MycrofD: maybe in the accounts of these mysterious beings that Luthor was presumably researching, those are the names that people ended up using to refer to them.

Comment: Just a note: The Flash's files actually state him as **Red Streak** . @PaulD.Waite, your point is valid. Could've been what people called them

Comment: Also also, WW is considered as a Meta. Lex isn't a very good detective if he did believe that

Comment: @Shreedhar: is Aquaman the Yellow Splash?

Comment: @Shreedhar Yes, there is `red streak' in the files. But the initials of the folder are FL. He could have chosen RS as initials for Red Streak instead of FL. Why FL?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yes, so some people have been calling Barry Allen as the Flash? Of course some have also been calling him Red Streak as the inside files suggest.

Comment: @MycrofD I meant that 'Red streak' was the name used by the public (like the way Iris did in CW's Flash). Lex, on the other hand used a code name, which coincidently, is Flash.

Comment: And to note, we do not know if by FL, Lex actually meant the Flash. Could've been an acronym for something else too.

Comment: Could be a nod to MoS how Superman never named himself Superman. The name was given to him based on the things he could do. Lex could have given them names that he thought fit.